# fmt.Println() stops printing chain at wrapped custom error (golang)

Tags: go

i want to know why `fmt.Println()` in Go/golang does print all the errors of some error-chain, when all wrapped errors in that error-chain where created with `fmt.Errorf()`. But when one of these errors is a custom error (that also wraps), `fmt.Println()` stops unwrapping and printing of error chain, at the custom error position.

Here is some simplified sample code:

```golang
type CustomError struct {
    Msg string
    Err error
}

func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    return e.Msg
}

func (e *CustomError) Unwrap() error {
    return e.Err
}

func main() {
    level1Err := errors.New("[Error in L1]: Boom")
    level2Err := fmt.Errorf("[Error in L2]: Wrap L1Err %w", level1Err)
    level3Err := fmt.Errorf("[Error in L3]: Wrap L2Err %w", level2Err)
    //level3Err := &CustomError{"[Error in L3]: Wrap L2Err", level2Err}
    level4Err := fmt.Errorf("[Error in L4]: Wrap L3Err %w", level3Err)
    fmt.Println(level4Err)
}

// Console output, when uncomment line28 and comment line29:
// [Error in L4]: Wrap L3Err [Error in L3]: Wrap L2Err [Error in L2]: Wrap L1Err [Error in L1]: Boom

// Console output, when uncomment line29 and comment line28:
// [Error in L4]: Wrap L3Err [Error in L3]: Wrap L2Err
```

Using Go 1.18

You can also found the sample code at https://github.com/MBODM/golang-error-chains-problem

Any help is rather appreciated

Comment: I have to add 2 things here: 1) I stopped with debugger at the `fmt.Println()` line and i can see, that all my errors are in chain (even when using custom error), including level1 error. 2) I used `errors.Unwrap()` from golang standard library and i can "chain-unwrap" all errors in some loop. Also there i got all the errors, including the level1 error. I always thought `fmt.Println()` also loops through all the Unwraps and print the errors, until `Unwrap()` returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help other ppls like me (i had a hard time with this, as a Go newbie), i answer my own question here:

It seems `fmt.Println(topLevelErr)` NOT unwraps all the errors and prints all that errors (by calling `.Error()` of every unwrapped error) with some `": "` as delimiter between the errors, as i thought initially. This is NOT what happens.

Instead all the go-lib errors do this by themselfes, by implementing the `error` interface in this way: Their `Error()` method (`error` implementation) tests if they have some wrapped error inside of themselfes and if so, print it "chained". This means they print their own error msg + `": "` + the wrapped error´s msg.

You can see this, if you have a look at the Go source code, as [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentioned below.

I personally would call this a rather stupid design. And totally unnecessary too, since all errors are wrapped anyway. Therefore all errors could be unwrapped manually, via `errors.Unwrap()` method from go-lib. When unwrapped, we (or also `fmt.Println()`) could print the error msg of every error, together with some delimiting `": "` stuff. This would be a way better design, than "*every error is wrapping the msg of it´s inner error inside it´s own msg*". I think that´s the reason why it confused me a lot. :)

<s>Also i advice you to do the same thing as i did in sample code below: At least let `fmt.Errorf()` create that wrapped error msg, instead of putting some `": "` string into it, by yourself. So it is granted, when the wrapped error behaviour changes, yours do also.</s>

Previous advice was incorrect, so i removed it. I accidentally thought `fmt.Errorf()` adds a `":"` to the text, when wrapping the error with `%w`. This is not true. As [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) already pointed out: Most stuff in the Go standard library do this in the implementation of their error interface:

> `return "own error text" + ": " + e.err.Error()`

So it doesnt matter, which of these you use, in your error implementation:

- `return fmt.Errorf("%s: %w", "own error text", e.err).Error()`
- `return "own error text" + ": " + e.err.Error()`

In both cases, you need to do the `": "` thingy by your own. In short: The `fmt.Errorf()` function does NOT automatically put the `": "` into the created error´s msg.

This shows, what´s all about:

```golang
type CustomError struct {
    Msg string
    Err error
}

func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    if e.Err != nil {
        // Added a ":" here, because fmt.Errorf() does NOT
        // automatically do this (as i accidentally thought above)!
        wrappedError := fmt.Errorf("%s: %w", e.Msg, e.Err)
        wrappedErrorMsg := wrappedError.Error()
        return wrappedErrorMsg
        // Also you can do this instead (like most go-lib pkgs):
        // return e.Msg + ": " + e.Err.Error()
    }
    return e.Msg
}

func (e *CustomError) Unwrap() error {
    return e.Err
}

func printAllWrappedErrors(topLevelError error) {
    fmt.Println(topLevelError)
}

func printCustomErrorOnly(topLevelError error) {
    var e *CustomError
    if errors.As(topLevelError, &e) {
        fmt.Println(e.Msg) // <-- This is the difference
    }
}

func printCustomErrorIncludingAllWrappedErrors(topLevelError error) {
    var e *CustomError
    if errors.As(topLevelError, &e) {
        fmt.Println(e) // <-- This is the difference
    }
}
```

For a better understanding just play around with the sample.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/MBODM/golang-error-chains-solution) on GitHub.

And big THX to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for the prompt help and the Kickoff! Was very helpful! :)

Have fun.

Comment: Thx a lot and thx for your prompt help! Was very appreciated!

Comment: does this help you anyhow ? https://go.dev/play/p/vkSFonXVzvj

Comment: @mh-cbon not sure what i see there? can you explain a bit further what this code does and what it should show us?

Comment: your code contains lots of duplication which can be avoided using proper embed mechanism, and then, everything works out of the box. It is only very sad that the error interface is a non exported built-in. When you declare such typed error type within a different package, you need to declare error as a local exported type so the embedded member is accessible from outside.

Comment: to expand my comment https://go.dev/play/p/aEy-UAYXg6M

Comment: `...it should show us`. out of curiosity, how many people on your side of the keyboard ?

Comment: just me. bad english, that‘s all. sorry. but to be honest, i have still no clue, what you are talking about here, or what your point is, you try to make. either we talk about different things here, or i am too new to golang to understand what the point is. i simply don’t understand WHAT the playground code shall show me. Do we talk about „proposed fields“ here ?

Comment: you are drawing false conclusions in your post, and it is being supported by a top scorer, it just seems a disaster to me. I was trying to show you, by the example, a way to implement custom error with ease.

Comment: @mh-cbon Interesting (and sorry if I misread those conclusions). Could you post an answer illustrating the right way to implement a custom error, while retaining the unwrap chain?

Comment: yeah, a well done example code would be very appreciated, since i still don’t get, as a golang newbie, what exactly @mh-cbon is pointing to. and if other golang newbies landing here, this would be very helpful for them too, i think.

Comment: point taken, it would require the declare an additional unwrap method, or to feed the underlying error membed directly to unwrap. And even probably have quiks, bitten once, i wont bet again.

Comment: it‘s like talking to an alien. :) i don’t understand a single word of your posts. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an existing example from [go source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ed5ebd32b3b8f66515522e8f09bc9dc023c0901c/src/os/error.go#L50-L58=):

```golang
// SyscallError records an error from a specific system call.
type SyscallError struct {
    Syscall string
    Err     error
}

func (e *SyscallError) Error() string { return e.Syscall + ": " + e.Err.Error() }

func (e *SyscallError) Unwrap() error { return e.Err }
```

So your `CustomError#Error()` method should be:

```golang
func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    if e.Err == nil {
        return e.Msg
    }
    return e.Msg + ": " + e.Err.Error()
}
```

See this [playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/oAxRY7smG6A):

```
[Error in L4]: Wrap L3Err [ErrorC in L3]: Wrap L2Err: [Error in L2]: Wrap L1Err [Error in L1]: Boom
```

Comment: I am not sure if i understand, what you are trying to tell me. :) Yes, above is exactly the reason why you implement `Unwrap()`. Also you have to look at err argument and what `Unwrap()` does. It results the saved and chained error (which itself does the same and so on). At least i always thought `fmt.Println()` unwraps all errors, until nil and prints the errors. If you unwrap the errors manually, by using `errors.Unwrap()` from go-lib, you can see ALL errors are there.

Comment: What? I still don´t get it. Everyone there has an `Unwrap()` method. Level1 error has an it from `fmt.Errorf()` and Level2 error has it from custom error. And the other 2 have it also from `fmt.Errorf()`. I really don´t get where some method shall be missing. And when you read my comment below the opening post, you see they indeed are all perfectly fine unwrappable, when using `errors.Unwrap()` from go-lib. In short: The problem is NOT that something isn´t wrapped. Otherwise you could not unwrap all of them manually, in a loop.

Comment: Sadly i can´t edit my opening post. Otherwise i would add the `errors.Unwrap()` loop (see here: https://pkg.go.dev/errors).

Comment: @MBODM I have found the actual root cause, and rewritten my answer accordingly. I have deleted my first comment, which was false.

Comment: Ah ok, np, thx! Slowly start to understand where you coming from. But since your solution works the way it does, this would mean that `fmt.Errorf()` creates text with „:“ stuff in it and from error to error the string inside the error grows. I always thought the error has just its own string text and the chained text with „:“ is made by `fmt.Println()` when running through chain and unwrapping all errors. Because, when the error strings grow, this is horrible stupid design by the go team.

Comment: Indeed, your solution works. It really seems they „safe“ the „stack“ inside the (growing) error strings. How stupid (and totally unnecessary). Now i ask myself if i shall better create a temporary err, with `fmt.Errorf()` inside my Unwrap() method and then return there the string result of that temp error. So i use the same string building logic, they do. Instead of typing my own “:“ string ?

Comment: @MBODM "f if i shall better create a temporary err, with fmt.Errorf() inside my Unwrap() method": no quite. I suspect `Unwrap()` is used by [`Is` and `As`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2580d0e08d5e9f979b943758d3c49877fb2324cb/src/errors/wrap.go#L24-L99=), not by `String()`. If your `CustomError#String()` does not take into account the wrapped error, it won't display it.

Comment: I answered my own question above, to make it clear for other comin here.